# How to add metrics to grafana for ThreadPoolTaskExecutor

Tags: java, spring, grafana

I found out that the response to the request lasts 3-5 seconds and 1.5k request per hours, so it's not good situation.

Endpoint - just get entity from database

```
@GetMapping
    @Async("operationThreadExecutor")
    public CompletableFuture<OperationDto> read()
```

I have next config

```
@Bean
    public AsyncTaskExecutor operationThreadExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(50);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("OperationSelfExecutor-");
        executor.initialize();
```

How to add metrics in grafana for current connection by this endpoint and queue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use `@Async` on a controller that doesn't do what you think it does. Just return a `CompletableFuture`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'll discuss it wih teamlead, but main question for me- about how to add metrics

Comment: Your question can be interpreted both ways, as you have an issue with throughput you want metrics. But what metrics? Looks like you want actually performance metrics for yur https requests and not so much on the threadpool (although min/max/idle can be useful). Are you using plain Spring or Spring Boot (the latter should already have metrics for threadpools). Anyway that `@Async` on the controller is actually crippeling your performance, while the weblayer has its own async mechanism, which will kick in if you just return a `CompletableFuture`. So things will improve when removing `@Async`.

Comment: @M.Deinum we use SpringBoot. I see metrics for all service, but here is task to add metrics only for this enpoint, that only one has a personal TaskExecutor. Need to see poolSize and Queue, if it possible

Comment: The metrics are alredy there just go find them. As stated the fix is to remove `@Async` as that is actually crippeling your service as it doesn't do what you think it does. You are actually fighting with the async servlet support with this.